How can I create a tarfile in memory in Erlang
I'm trying to write an Erlang function that takes a list of binaries and packs them into a single binary.
Looking at erl_tar in the standard lib, it seems the create function will only take a filename, not a binary, so my plan was to use open and add to implement the function.
Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to get the open function working either.
My minimal example of trying to open a binary for writing:
case erl_tar:open({binary, <<>>}, [write, compressed]) of
     {ok, _Td} -> io:put_chars("Opened binary")
end.

causes a runtime error:
runtime error: Erlang error

No Erlang function clause matched the arguments it was called with.

stacktrace:
  erl_tar.open1 erl_tar.erl:579

Looking at the documentation and source for erl_tar, I think this might be a bug? I'm not exactly an erlanger.
I'll open an issue, but in the meantime, if someone knows how to pack a tarfile in memory in erlang it would unblock me.

Do not use create function, use lower level interface: init function allows you to specify what should be done with data. The documentation includes an example showing how to write to a file using init, adapt it so you construct a binary instead. Then you use add to add files to the archive, and close to finish.
It might be tricky though since the callbacks in init do  not allow to pass modified state for the next calls. You will need something which has the appropriate subset of file module, but creates a binary. It would be indeed useful if erl_tar supported in-memory creation directly.
